# MOUSE_UP and MOUSE_DOWN issues in flash when using it in drag drop

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mouseevent, flash-cs5

could you please help me figure out what caused the unexpected output in my program? i have used flash cs5 and as3. and it is a drag and drop game.

no errors where found but my **MOUSE_UP** and **MOUSE_DOWN** is not functioning the way it is suppose to do. (in my opinion)

i say this because, when i test the codes, when i click the object. mouse down kind of like do the functions of a click or something like that. i cannot drop the object.

this is the set of codes i used for my drag and drop

```
 wintersquash_mc.buttonMode = true;
 wintersquash_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 wintersquash_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

 function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
event.target.startDrag(true);
event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
 }
 function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
event.target.stopDrag();
var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
if (event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget)
{
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
    event.target.buttonMode = false;
    event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
    event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
    scorer++;
    score.text = String(scorer);
}
else
{
    event.target.x = objectoriginalX;
    event.target.y = objectoriginalY;
}
 }
```

hope someone could tell me why it doesn't work properly :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your `MOUSE_UP` to the stage, not your movieclip. That should ensure that the event will be caught no matter where the mouse is.

Additionally, you may consider only adding your `MOUSE_UP` listener once pickupObject() runs. Like this:

```
wintersquash_mc.buttonMode = true;
wintersquash_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
    objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
}
```

This will require your class to have a reference to the Stage object. Also, you'll have to explicitly remove the listener from the stage when you're done with it. Give this a try, though, see if it works for you.

Comment: shouldn't it be MOUSE_DOWN? since when you drop, you press it?

Comment: i tried doing what you said, but the target box is like running away from the object. what i meant was if i drag the wintersquash_mc object into the targetwintersquash_mc, the target position itself to where the object was once where. and at the same time, mouse_down still uses the click function. from what i have read, when i use mouse_down, its function is simply when you press and not yet release the button,an action will occur. but mine functions like a clike, how come? :(

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle dragging like this:

```
wintersquash_mc.buttonMode = true;

wintersquash_mc.mouseChildren = false;
//this way you won't start dragging i.e. a sub-movieclip of the button

wintersquash_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.startDrag(true);

    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    // is it necessary to add the clip to its parent?
    // I would rather make a var on the root,
    // and dump the event.target into that like this:
    // root.nowDragged = event.target;

    objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
    objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
}

function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    root.nowDragged.stopDrag(true);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
    // this removes the listener to prevent false alarms on other mouse ups
    //... (rest of your code)
}
```

I hope this helped.